# C preprocessor macro to create lookup table

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

I have a lookup table which links all my 'two char commands' e.g. AA, AB, SS, to their corresponding function addresses in alphabetical order of the first char.

The row, i.e. branch, in command_list correspond to their ascii values minus 'A'
i.e. 
`command_list[0]` is all the "A" commands
`command_list[1]` is all the "B" commands.

Furthermore the second char is assigned a 'twig' under the 'branch'

e.g. if command AA was assigned to twig 0....
`command "AA"` becomes `command_list['A' -'A']->twig[0]` which becomes `command_list[0]->twig[0]` and then I can call the function at address `command_list[0]->twig[0]->leaf_function`

My questions are

1. Using `#define CREATE_TWIG(CHAR_1, CHAR_2) twig_t twig_##CHAR_1##CHAR_2  = {.twig_id =  'CHAR_1', .leaf_function = &command_##CHAR_1##CHAR_2};` I can create a twig, but the `.twig_id` is messed up and is always assigned (int) 1 instead of the decimal value of `CHAR_1`. Why is this?
2. How to do I automate this part using macros? Note: the number of twigs can be an non-negative int up to 26 i.e. A to Z

```
twig_t * A_twigs[2] =  {&twig_AD, &twig_AS};

branch_t A_branch = {.branch_id = 'A', .num_twigs = 2, .twigs = A_twigs};

tree command_list[1] = {&A_branch};
```

The rest of the code/typedefs/structs

```
 typedef struct{
        uint8_t twig_id;
        void * leaf_function;
    }twig_t;

    typedef struct{
        uint8_t branch_id;
        uint8_t num_twigs;
        twig_t **twigs;
    }branch_t;

    typedef branch_t* tree;

    void command_AD(void);
    void command_AS(void);

    #define CREATE_TWIG(CHAR_1, CHAR_2) twig_t twig_##CHAR_1##CHAR_2  = {.twig_id =  'CHAR_1', .leaf_function = &command_##CHAR_1##CHAR_2};

    CREATE_TWIG(A,S)

    twig_t twig_AD = {.twig_id = 'D', .leaf_function = &command_AD};


    twig_t * A_twigs[2] =  {&twig_AD, &twig_AS};

    branch_t A_branch = {.branch_id = 'A', .num_twigs = 2, .twigs = A_twigs};

    tree command_list[1] = {&A_branch};
```

Comment: The preprocessor cannot create character constants like `'D'` from `D`. (But the Microsoft compilers have the non-standard ["Charizing operator"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/charizing-operator-hash-at?view=vs-2019).) An alternative to macros is to create the table with a separate program, which writes an include file and which can be part of the build process.

Comment: Not a direct answer: Wouldn't it be easier to just have an `array_of_functions[26][26] ` as you have to calculate the two indices in any case? Do you need to store the IDs in the structs?

Comment: @HelmutWollmersdorfer ideally I would to make my life easy, but this is for an embedded system, i.e. low RAM, low processing power, hence the decision for a lookup table. The original code had a loop to check each incoming command with the complete list of commands every single time, return a code, and then running through a list of codes to execute a subroutine...not very efficient. The lookup table seems more efficient to me, but I'm open to ideas.

Comment: @hhonab1 An array 26 x 26 = 676 entries of only pointers. If there is no leaf-function just let the field be zero (if there is no leaf-function with pointer zero). Try to estimate  the space and runtime of both variants and compare them. It depends on how many functions exist.

Answer (score 0):

leave ' ' off? CHAR_1 contain your character ascii value.

Comment: This doesn't work as the preprocessor output will be ```{.twig_id = A,...``` making the compiler think that A is a variable, and then throw an error saying A is undeclared.

Comment: it works! there is some other issues to.  <br/> <pre/> #define CREATE_TWIG(CHAR_1, CHAR_2) twig_t twig_##CHAR_1##CHAR_2  = {.twig_id =  #CHAR_1[0], .leaf_function = &command_##CHAR_1##CHAR_2};<code/>

Comment: Doesn't compile for me
```
../main/example_spp_acceptor_demo.c:140:16: error: initializer element is not constant
 CREATE_TWIG(A,X)
                ^
```

Comment: change : void (*leaf_function)(void); in struct twig_t. the typeof function pointer is wrong

Comment: this is comment for upper comments but if you use table array_of_functions[26][26] then you can write linker file where you remove those elements what you do not need . so unused memory is not reserved.